# Image Sequence -> Timeline relation. How could I make an image sequence start at frame 20?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, image, timeline

I'm working in EVEE right now and I am trying to make an image sequence start in the middle of the timeline. Is there a fairly simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes.  Set the "start frame" on the image texture node to be equal to the timeline frame you want the video to start at.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks man! That's exactly what I was looking for!